# Search Max and Min from View

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask about my sql to find max and min from view.

I have create a view :

```
create VIEW Count_Of_Appointment AS
SELECT ap.doctorID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfAppointment, CONCAT(d.surname,'', d.given) AS doctor_name
FROM appointment AS ap Inner join doctor AS d
    ON ap.doctorid = d.doctorID
GROUP BY doctorID
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Now, I want to find min + name of doctor from using that view.

Here is my code :

```
SELECT a2.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT ap.doctorID, COUNT(*) AS Number, CONCAT(d.surname,'', d.given) AS doctor_name
    FROM appointment AS ap Inner join doctor AS d
        ON ap.doctorid = d.doctorID
    GROUP BY doctorID
    ORDER BY COUNT(*)
    )a2
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT MIN(Number) AS NumberOfAppointment 
FROM
    (
    SELECT ap.doctorID, COUNT(*) AS Number, CONCAT(d.surname,'', d.given) AS doctor_name
    FROM appointment AS ap Inner join doctor AS d
        ON ap.doctorid = d.doctorID
    GROUP BY doctorID
    ORDER BY COUNT(*)
    )a1
)b 
ON a2.Number = b.NumberOfAppointment
```

I was doing that code before use view. How do I convert them using FROM VIEW Count_Of_Appointment ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get min and max aggregate function using MySQL

```
SELECT student_name, MIN(test_score), MAX(test_score)
    FROM student
    GROUP BY student_name;
```

and if you want make it as a view

```
CREATE VIEW vw_student_score AS 
   SELECT student_name, MIN(test_score), MAX(test_score)
    FROM student
    GROUP BY student_name;
```